# Ionic collection-repeat with ion-radio

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem with setting checked on selected value using Icon collection-repeat with ion-radio.

Using the collection-repeat, if the selected item is the first item in the list, setting checked wouldn't work. To make it works I found, I need to make a delay assigning list data.

(If using ng-repeat, it works. But the list could be long, so I need to use the collection-repeat)

Example,

Template)

```
<ion-content class="has-header" ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
  <div class="list">
    <ion-radio
      collection-repeat="item in list"
      ng-model="selectedItem"
      ng-value="item.id">
      {{ item.n }}
    </ion-radio>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Controller)

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
})
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.selectedItem = 1; // the first item

    var list = [];

  for (index = 1; index < 3; ++index) {
    list.push({id: index, n: 'Item n. ' + index});
    }

  $scope.list = list;

});
```

The first item of the list wouldn't be checked. To make it works,

replace

> $scope.list = list;

with

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.list = list;
  }, 500);
```

I want to know why it happened, and I don't think the 500ms is guaranteed, so I need to know right way to solve this. Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes complete sense that you want to use collection-repeat over ng-repeat since the list could potentially be very long, and would be unnecessary to render all the items in the DOM at once using ng-repeat. Unfortunately this is a **[known bug](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/collection-repeat-bug-with-radio-buttons-and-ng-model/28097)** within Ionic from what I have read and the work around to this is quite hacky. For instance the code below works with making active the 2nd radio:

**Controller**

```
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope, $timeout) {

$scope.data = {
    selectedItem: 2
};

var list = [];

for (index = 1; index < 3; ++index) {
    list.push({id: index, n: 'Item n. ' + index});
}

$scope.list = list;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-content class="has-header" ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
 <div class="list">
  <ion-radio collection-repeat="item in list" ng-model="data.selectedItem" ng-value="item.id">
   {{ item.n }}
  </ion-radio>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

But when you change the selected item to 1, it does not show. Below is a workaround for what you are looking for. Start your loop at 0 and then hide that item using CSS (like I said "hacky"), give it a try.

**Controller**

```
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope, $timeout) {

$scope.data = {
    selectedItem: 1
};

var list = [];

for (index = 0; index < 5; ++index) {
    list.push({id: index, n: 'Item n. ' + index});
}

$scope.list = list;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-content class="has-header" ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
 <div class="list">
<ion-radio
  collection-repeat="item in list" ng-model="data.selectedItem" ng-value="item.id" item-height="54" item-width="100.5%">
  {{ item.n }}
</ion-radio>
```

**CSS**

```
.item-radio:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}

.item-radio {
  margin-top: -54px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sam, thank you for your answer! I don't want to touch the list which is coming from Remote, so for now I will use the delay way, and it works Okay so far :p.

Comment: @Expertwannabe I'll keep a look out and see if a fix occurs and update my answer. But for now your delay may be your best bet.